# ng-click stops working after page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have already built a big part of my app the same way I am building this page. It's a login page that checks if the user exists on the database.

The **problem** is that the ng-click directive is driving me crazy! It works only when it wants, I hit refresh: **it works!** I hit refresh again: **it stops working.** I hit refresh one more time: **it works!**

I copied and pasted the example from the ngClick documentation page and the same thing happens. So, the problem is not with my controller.

**Code:**

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
<span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
```

**Controller:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
  $scope.terapeuta = {};

  $scope.logar = function (terapeuta) {
      console.log('test');
  }

});
```

I suspect that it maybe caused by something not loading properly. But everything other than ngClick works perfectly.

Comment: Any errors in your development tools, the console or network tabs?  When `ng-click` doesn't work, do you at least see `count: 0` instead of `count: {{count}}`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by removing the **ngTouch** module.

It was causing some sort of conflict, it is now working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encapsulate incrementing the *count* variable in a separate function in your controller and call it with ng-click, see if that works.